# Upload Image to Server using Multipart and Request Body in Android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit2, multipart

I am stuck in between a strange issue of uploading image file to server. Although I did upload file several times before, but this time I don't understand what is the issue.

I get the file path of respective file but **RequestBody** returns **null**. Below I mentioned what library I'm using.

I am using **kotlin**, **MultiPart** and **RequestBody** for file upload.

```
implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1'
```

Below is my code which I wrote for file upload. In which you can see **GalleryCameraUtility.getImageRequestBody(imageFile)** returns null for file.

File path from mobile device **/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/test_image.jpg**

```
 fun addNewCompany(companyName: String, email: String,imageFile: File, ownerName: String, address: String, companyDetails: String){

        val companyNameBody: RequestBody = companyName.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val emailBody: RequestBody = email.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val fileData: RequestBody? = GalleryCameraUtility.getImageRequestBody(imageFile)
        val ownerNameBody: RequestBody = ownerName.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val addressBody: RequestBody = address.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val userIdBody: RequestBody = PreferenceHelper.readUserIdPref(Constants.USER_ID).toString()
            .toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())

        addCompanyRepo.addNewCompanyApi(companyNameBody, emailBody, fileData, ownerNameBody, addressBody, userIdBody)
    }


class GalleryCameraUtility {
    companion object{

        fun getImageRequestBody(sourceFile: File) : RequestBody? {
            var requestBody: RequestBody? = null
            Thread {
                val mimeType = getMimeType(sourceFile);
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    Log.e("file error", "Not able to get mime type")
                    return@Thread
                }
                try {
                    requestBody = sourceFile.path.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                        /*MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart(serverImageKey, uploadedFileName,sourceFile.asRequestBody(mimeType.toMediaTypeOrNull()))
                            .build()*/
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                    Log.e("File upload", "failed")
                }
            }.start()

            return requestBody;
        }

        // url = file path or whatever suitable URL you want.
        private fun getMimeType(file: File): String? {
            var type: String? = null
            val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.path)
            if (extension != null) {
                type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
            }
            return type
        }
    }
}
```

I spent so many hours on this but not able to find solution. Please help me out on this.

Comment: requestBody = sourceFile.path.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()).
 
In this line do'nt use .path only sourceFile.ToRequestBody() .

You  need to create File using val sourceFile =File(filePath) then like 
requestBody = sourceFile.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()).

Comment: Your thread has not yet finished when getImageRequestBody returns.

Comment: @UmeshYadav I tried requestBody = sourceFile.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()). But sourceFile.toRequestBody is not acceptable. It is accepting **sourceFile.asRequestBody** but still not working.